# Remove duplicates from single column power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

From this original table,

[image]

I made a second table (using power query).

[image]

This second table is to be used for data validation purposes, and I need it to depend on the first table so that any changes will follow through. The problem I'm running into is that my second table is not quite how I want it, I would like to remove any duplicates from each individual column. When I try to remove duplicates in power query, it removes whole rows (which makes sense, I agree), is there a way to remove duplicates from single columns?

Here's the M code I'm using to get from table1 to table2

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
   #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Grade", "fb", "fv", "fc", "fcp", "ft", "E", "E05"}),
   #"Grouped Rows" = Table.FromColumns(Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Catégorie"}, {{"Count", each List.InsertRange([Essence],0,List.Distinct([Catégorie]))}})[Count]),
   #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Grouped Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in 
   #"Promoted Headers"
```

Comment: I don't think so .. you will need a separate query for each column

Comment: I agree with @Slai. You need separate queries, because in Power Query each row of data is a record across all available columns.

Comment: I added the M code i'm using to go from table1 to table2... Seems likes I might be able to get this to work by adding a list.distinct somewhere in there, but I'm not familiar enough with M code to know where.

Comment: You don't need separate queries, but you likely do need to go beyond the GUI and write some M code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Source` table with columns `A`, `B`, and `C` and want to return a table of each column with duplicates removed, then you can write M code like this:

```
= Table.FromColumns({   
      List.Distinct(Source[A]),
      List.Distinct(Source[B]),
      List.Distinct(Source[C])},
      {"A","B","C"})
```

More generically (without using explicit column names), you can do it in a few steps like this:

```
ToColumns = Table.FromList(Table.ToColumns(Source), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
RemoveDuplicates = Table.TransformColumns(ToColumns, {{"Column1", each List.Distinct(_)}}),
FromColumns = Table.FromColumns(RemoveDuplicates[Column1], Table.ColumnNames(Source))
```

Comment: So I'm going to try to piggy back on this because I can't get your code to work for my query. I have a created column within my query that I need to remove duplicates from on just that column and not have it delete the entire row. The created column is named Invoice+Tax, I can provide more information as needed I'm just hoping someone can help me tweak the above code to make it work for me. I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Please post as a separate question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Alright, I posted a separate question with details, I appreciate any help given. The link is below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817863/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-single-power-query-column-without-removing-entries

Answer (score -1):

if you are using a new version of excel go to data menu from the top menu then > highlight the column you want and press remove duplicates.
it remove only values from the selected column

first:

[image]

then:

[image]

Comment: That is not what the question is about.