# How to remove duplicates from single Power Query column without removing entries rows?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a merged query that I need to remove duplicates for my Invoice+Tax column without removing the entire row for that duplicate. I just need to remove the duplicate values for that one column. As you can see from the below picture I am trying to remove duplicate values from the Invoice+Tax column. But I need to keep the row, just remove the duplicate values, for example I have highlighted below what should be removed, anything not highlighted needs to remain. I have also included my code to this point below the picture.

[image]

```
let
Order = Order,
Source = Sql.Database("jansql01", "mas500_app"),
dbo_vdvInvoiceLine = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="vdvInvoiceLine"]}[Data],
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(dbo_vdvInvoiceLine,{"Description", "ItemID", "STaxClassID", "ExtAmt", "FreightAmt", "TranID", "TradeDiscAmt", "FormattedGLAcctNo", "Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3", "SalesOrder", "CustID", "CustName", "TranDate", "PostDate", "City", "StateID", "ItemClassID", "UseTaxRate", "ReleaseSO", "Job Number"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each Text.Contains([SalesOrder], Order)),
#"Added Material Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Material", each if [ItemClassID] <> "INSTALLATION" then [ExtAmt] else 0),
#"Added Installation Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Material Column", "Installation", each if [ItemClassID] = "INSTALLATION" then [ExtAmt] else 0),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Installation Column",{"TranID"},vdvInvoice,{"TranID"},"vdvInvoice",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded vdvInvoice" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "vdvInvoice", {"STaxAmt"}, {"vdvInvoice.STaxAmt"}),
#"Extracted Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded vdvInvoice",{{"TranDate", DateTime.Date, type date}, {"PostDate", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
#"Added Invoice+Tax" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Date", "Invoice+Tax", each [TranID]&Number.ToText([vdvInvoice.STaxAmt]))

in
#"Added Invoice+Tax"
```

Comment: Can I ask why? That's a really odd thing to do!

Comment: It does seem rather odd. It can be done, but I'd bet there's a better way to handle the situation.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to pull in our material, install, freight and tax cost for our install jobs. Well everything except for Tax resides in our invoice lines query whereas Tax is only at the invoice level in the invoice query. Well I need invoice lines to be able to break out material and installation but have to get tax from invoices. Well since there are multiple lines for each invoice when I merge the queries I get the tax duplicated. So I'm trying to remove those duplicate values without removing the entire row because I need the data on those rows. Sorry for the long-winded response.

Comment: Well I have both of the tables loading to Excel with the invoice number being common between them so I'm pulling this data into a pivot table. I've tried to pull the tax from the Invoice table but it won't create the relationship like it should. I've never done that before so might not be doing it right but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any reason to do it, but if you really want to, replace the bottom two rows with

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Invoice+Tax", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Invoice+Tax2", each if [Index]=0 then [#"Invoice+Tax"] else if #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[#"Invoice+Tax"]=[#"Invoice+Tax"] then null else [#"Invoice+Tax"]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, just for the heck of it:

After your line that says, `#"Added Invoice+Tax" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Date", "Invoice+Tax", each [TranID]&Number.ToText([vdvInvoice.STaxAmt]))`, add a comma and then, in place of,

```
in
#"Removed Columns"
```

add this:

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Invoice+Tax", {"Invoice+Tax"}, {{"AllData", each Table.FromColumns({[Installation],[vdvInvoice.STaxAmt],{[#"Invoice+Tax"]{0}}},{"Installation", "vdvInvoice.STaxAmt", "Invoice+Tax"}), type table}}),
#"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"AllData"}),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns2", "AllData", {"Installation", "vdvInvoice.STaxAmt", "Invoice+Tax"}, {"Installation", "vdvInvoice.STaxAmt", "Invoice+Tax"})
in
#"Expanded AllData"
```

What the #Grouped Rows" line, above, does is that it groups by the Invoice+Tax, with a sub-table for each Invoice+Tax from the original table's columns. But in making each sub-table, while it pulls *all* Installation and vdvInvoice.STaxAmt rows that are associated with each Invoice+Tax from the original table, it only pulls *the first* Invoice+Tax row associated with each Invoice+Tax from the original table. `Table.FromColumns({[Installation],[vdvInvoice.STaxAmt],{[#"Invoice+Tax"]{0}}}...`is basically saying to get all rows within columns Installation and vdvInvoice.STaxAmt, and only list item 0 (row 1) of the list which is actually the Invoice+Tax column.

The complete query: Your initial query that you provided above with my little part added, would be:

```
let
Order = Order,
Source = Sql.Database("jansql01", "mas500_app"),
dbo_vdvInvoiceLine = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="vdvInvoiceLine"]}[Data],
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(dbo_vdvInvoiceLine,{"Description", "ItemID", "STaxClassID", "ExtAmt", "FreightAmt", "TranID", "TradeDiscAmt", "FormattedGLAcctNo", "Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3", "SalesOrder", "CustID", "CustName", "TranDate", "PostDate", "City", "StateID", "ItemClassID", "UseTaxRate", "ReleaseSO", "Job Number"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each Text.Contains([SalesOrder], Order)),
#"Added Material Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Material", each if [ItemClassID] <> "INSTALLATION" then [ExtAmt] else 0),
#"Added Installation Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Material Column", "Installation", each if [ItemClassID] = "INSTALLATION" then [ExtAmt] else 0),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Installation Column",{"TranID"},vdvInvoice,{"TranID"},"vdvInvoice",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded vdvInvoice" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "vdvInvoice", {"STaxAmt"}, {"vdvInvoice.STaxAmt"}),
#"Extracted Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded vdvInvoice",{{"TranDate", DateTime.Date, type date}, {"PostDate", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
#"Added Invoice+Tax" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Date", "Invoice+Tax", each [TranID]&Number.ToText([vdvInvoice.STaxAmt])),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Invoice+Tax", {"Invoice+Tax"}, {{"AllData", each Table.FromColumns({[Installation],[vdvInvoice.STaxAmt],{[#"Invoice+Tax"]{0}}},{"Installation", "vdvInvoice.STaxAmt", "Invoice+Tax"}), type table}}),
#"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"AllData"}),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns2", "AllData", {"Installation", "vdvInvoice.STaxAmt", "Invoice+Tax"}, {"Installation", "vdvInvoice.STaxAmt", "Invoice+Tax"})
in
#"Expanded AllData"
```